# How to work with complex numbers in java?

Tags: java, complex-numbers

I am new to java and not sure how to deal with complex numbers in java. I am writing a code for my project. I have used Euler's identity, exp(i*theeta) = cos(theeta)+i*Sin(theeta) to find exp(i*2*pi*f). I have to multiply this resulting complex number with another number from an array "d". Here is what I have done

```
Complex Data[][] = new Complex[20][20];
for (int j = 0; j < d.size(); j++){
    for (int k = 0; k<20; k++){
        for (int l = 0; l<20; l++){
            double re = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * f);
            double im = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f);
            Complex p = new Complex(re, im);
            Data[k][l] = ((d.get(j) * p.getReal()), (d.get(j) * p.getImaginary()));     
        }   
    }
}
```

I am, however, getting an error on the expression `Data[k][l] = ((d.get(j) * p.getReal()), (d.get(j) * p.getImaginary()));` saying "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". 
Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to assign an instance of `Complex` to `Data[k][l]`, then you will generally need something of the form `Data[k][l] = new Complex(...)`. What you currently have seems to be trying to assign two comma separated values to a variable, which would never work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply khelwood. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work like in C++ with the copy constructors or overloaded assignment operators.

You'll have to explicitly call the constructor for your complex, like in

```
Data[k][l] = new Complex(realValue, imaginaryVal);
```

Of course, you'll need use methods of the complex to multiply two numbers, because there's no notion of any other operator overload in Java.

So, perhaps the `Complex` class might have some method which you might be able to use instead of the operators, like

```
class Complex {
  public static Complex mul(Complex c0, Complex c1) {
    double r0=c.getRe(), r1=c1.getRe();
    double i0=c.getIm(), i1=c1.getIm();
    return new Complex(r0*r1-i0*i1, r0*i1+r1*i0);
  }

  public static Complex mulStore(Complex res, Complex c0, Complex c1) {
    double r0=c.getRe(), r1=c1.getRe();
    double i0=c.getIm(), i1=c1.getIm();
    if(res==null) {
      res=new Complex();
    }
    res.setRe(r0*r1-i0*i1);
    res.setIm(r0*i1+r1*i0);
    return res;
  }

  // equiv with this *= rhs;
  public void mulAssign(Complex rhs) {
    // perform the "this * rhs" multiplication and 
    // store the result in this. 
    Complex.mulStore(this, rhs, this);
  } 

}
```